# How to hide drop-downs when clicking Tableau buttons using Tableau Reader

Tags: tableau-api

how do I hide the little drop-down menus on a Tableau worksheet used as a button....

See picture... [image: Sample Menu with annoying Drop-down]

Everything is working perfectly in Tableau Desktop, but in Reader I get these drop-downs that I don't want the user to see or have to be bothered by?

The buttons don't show this if i a browsing through them in Desktop--only in Tableau Reader.

Are you able to see the picture?  Let me know, if not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those controls should go away when the dashboard is put into presentation mode by clicking this icon.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Yes... they do go away in Desktop Presentation mode.  But, I am looking at what our users will use, and they do not go away in Tableau Reader... which is very surprising to me.... When, I open the project in TR they are there.  Oddly enough, though, the other worksheets on the dashboard do not show these drop-downs when clicked.  Getting rid of these drop-downs, is my final issue for this set of dashboards.

Comment: I didn't realize you could also be in presentation mode in Tableau Reader.  I assumed incorrectly that Tableau Reader was already in presentation mode.  This worked perfectly.  That's an easy thing to explain to users.  Thank you.